# why useRef() hook is setting to null after firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword() call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, use-ref

`useRef()` is used like :

```
const firstname = useRef('');

const lastname = useRef('');

const email = useRef('');

const passwordOne = useRef('');
```

When I am writing it like this:

```
try {
    const authUser = await Firebase.auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email.current.value,
            passwordOne.current.value
        );
    await Firebase.firestore.doc(`users/${authUser.user.uid}`).set({
        firstname: firstname.current.value,
        lastname: lastname.current.value,
        email: email.current.value
    });
    history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
}
catch (error) {
    setError(error.message);
}
```

I am getting an error that `cannot read property value of null`.

But this is working :

```
try {
    const user = {
        firstname: firstname.current.value,
        lastname: lastname.current.value,
        email: email.current.value
    };
    const authUser = await Firebase.auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email.current.value,
            passwordOne.current.value
        );
    await Firebase.firestore.doc(`users/${authUser.user.uid}`).set(user);
    history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
}
catch (error) {
    setError(error.message);
}
```

How? And why?

Comment: In the first case you are getting the value at the time that `.set()` is called.  In the second case you are getting the value from when you first enter the `try` block.  There might be changes while `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is executing.  But using refs here is not the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

one important thing you have to keep in mind is that you're dealing with asynchronous code, the time in which the statements with `await` will try to access the ref properties is not guaranteed and the refs might not be initialized yet.

My advice will be to refactor your code to use a [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) with `useState` instead of handing DOM refs with `useRef`

> In HTML, form elements such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select> typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with setState().
> We can combine the two by making the React state be the “single source of truth”. Then the React component that renders a form also controls what happens in that form on subsequent user input. An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a “controlled component”.

Comment: before using useRef(), I had used useState(). But I don't want too render the same component too many times. That's why I decided to use useRef(). So, Is it a good approach ?

Comment: @roperzh Can you please answer it ?